# I can't install MS Visual Studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install MS Visual Studio 2010 in my laptop, but it get stuck on [this](http://www.kodyaz.com/images/visual-studio-2010/microsoft-visual-studio-2010-setup-vs2010-ultimate.PNG) point. I've installed it several times before, but now i can't. Even I installed my windows again but the problem is same. I'm using windows 7 ultimate. Please help me if someone knows about it.

Comment: 2010? 2013's out and 2015 is close, just install the new one.

Comment: And another question: Why do you want to install a beta release? Like @simonzack mentioned, if there is no special reason to install VS2010, go with a newer release.

Answer (score 0):

If your persistent on using the VS 2010 Beta 2 version, try this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/067d5920-fa6d-4393-93d8-d208d87c2c3e/visual-studio-2010-express-beta-2-on-windows-7-professional-x86?forum=Vsexpressinstall

but I recommend to skip it and install VS 2013 as adviced by @simonzack and @Horizon_Net